# MySQL não conecta ao servidor

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Olá, fui entrar no phpmyadmin e apareceu isso, onde sera que deve ser o problema ??

[image]

Codigo

```
$coneccao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "MINHASENHA");
mysqli_select_db($coneccao, "luppbox");
```

o servidor esta hospedado em um VPS, em lugar de localhost devo colocar o ip do meu servidor ??

Comment: Isso eu escolho na hora de pegar as informaçoes

Comment: Isso é um erro de config no seu phpmyadmin.

Comment: E como faço pra configurar certo ??

Comment: Você postou um código de conexão ao mysql, se a conexão não estiver funcionando, pode ser que o problema seja no mysql, por isso o phpmyadmin pode estar dando erro também.

Comment: Estou montando um passo a passo aqui. Fica tranquilo :)

Comment: Blz, vlw pela ajuda, fico esperando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Abra o phpmyadmin e logue como root.
2. Crie um banco de dados chamado `phpmyadmin`
3. Crie um usuário chamado `pma` e defina o "host" para o hostname ou IP do seu web server (se o seu web server e seu MySQL estiverem na mesma máquina use `localhost`), anote a senha e garanta ao novo usuário acesso total ao banco de dados `phpmyadmin`. É recomendado que esse usuário não tenha acesso a mais nada além desse banco de dados.
4. Vá ao diretório de instalação do phpmyadmin, onde você deve encontrar um sub-diretório chamado `examples`.
5. Em `examples` você vai encontrar um arquivo chamado `create_tables.sql`. Abra no editor de texto.
6. No phpMyAdmin, selecione o banco `phpmyadmin` e clique na aba "SQL".
7. Copie e cole todo o texto de `create_tables.sql` para a caixa de texto e rode a query
8. Abra o arquivo `config.inc.php` no diretório de instalação do phpMyAdmin e adicione as seguintes linhas (ou altere as configurações existentes se elas já estiverem lá):

   ```php
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['controluser'] = 'pma';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['controlpass'] = '<your password>';

   $cfg['Servers'][1]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['history'] = 'pma_history';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
   ```
9. Salve e feche o arquivo.
10. Deslogue do phpMyAdmin
11. Logue de novo

Problema resolvido.

Comment: Cada eu não achei create_tables.sql, procurei pelo VPS inteiro

Comment: Achou a pasta do phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na pasta do phpMyAdmin, se por acaso não encontrar lá, o arquivo está no github pelo link https://github.com/i-MSCP/phpmyadmin/blob/master/examples/create_tables.sql

Comment: Só tem ums conf.d e esta vazia

Comment: Mano, eu fiz tudo certinho, os erros sumiram, porem continua sem conseguir mandar informaçoes pro banco de dados